# Loading URL patterns without activating them?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My Django project has two applications in it: a web tool and a REST interface.

I run the REST interface on my database system (e.g. `db.myhost.com`). This interface only has URL patterns that correspond to the various REST endpoints:

```
app_name = "rest"
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^report/id/(?P<rid>[0-9]+)/$', views.ReportByID.as_view()),
    url(r'^report/slug/(?P<slug>[a-z0-9-]+)/$', views.ReportBySlug.as_view()),
]
```

Part of the data that these views ultimately show need links to the other application in my project (which I host on a separate system). That application also has URL patterns:

```
app_name = "mytool"
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^some/cool/path/$', views.some_cool_path),
]
```

The REST interface only enables the REST URL patterns, since I only want to serve REST endpoints via that host:

```
# On my REST system
ROOT_URL = "myproject.rest_urls"
```

Is there a way that I can get the REST application to load the `mytool` URL patterns without activating them? I don't want a user to be able to browse to `db.myhost.com/some/cool/path/` and get an error because that path isn't served on that host, it's served by the web tool server instead. It would be helpful, however, to be able to use `reverse()` to get the `mytool` URLs, even if they are just relative fragments (i.e. `/some/cool/path` ... I could always prepend the server name, which is unlikely to ever change).

I could hard-code the necessary paths, but I'd like to avoid having to do that in case they need to change in the future.

Comment: It seems you're hosting them as separate applications so treat them the same way. If the REST service needs to access the tool service then set the tool service in the REST settings as you would do for any other third party service. This will help you decouple them and make it easier if ever you decide to separate the code base too

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Is there an example of this kind of setup anywhere that I can look at?

Comment: No, I'm just saying you should do it the normal way you call hardcoding. First, why do you need the url? to make a request to it as a different service? if so, then just store the url in your settings the url the same way you would store of a third-party API you're making request to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it using django test utils `override_settings` decorator. It will use temporary settings so, it will not have any effect on the live site.

## settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # .....
    'mytool',
    # .....
]
ROOT_URL = "myproject.rest_urls"
```

## mytool/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('news/<slug:slug>/', views.NewsDetailView.as_view(), name='news_detail'),
]
```

## mytool/utils.py

```
from django.test.utils import override_settings
from django.urls import reverse

def temp_reverse(url_conf, url_name, url_args=(), url_kwargs={}):

    @override_settings(ROOT_URLCONF=url_conf)
    def get_reverse(url_name, *args, **kwargs):
        return reverse(url_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    return get_reverse(url_name, *url_args, **url_kwargs)
```

## accessing the reverse for unregistered urls

```
from mytool.urils import temp_reverse
url = temp_reverse('mytool.urls', 'news_detail', url_kwargs={'slug': 'django-awesome'})
print(url)
# output: /news/django-awesome/
```

Comment: Very clever. Thanks for the tip!